# How to create docker file combining with spring boot and python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I am using python scripts in my project.

I need to add python 3 along with java in docker file.

Comment: Typically you'd try to set this up with two separate containers if you could; use something like Flask to provide an HTTP interface, or use a message queue like RabbitMQ for asynchronous communication between the two components.  What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a docker file with derive from java and install python 3 like the following example:

```
FROM openjdk

RUN apt update -y && apt install -y python3

# Add here you command script
CMD ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Antonio Petricca